# fscanf in C segmentation error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I am trying to read in values from a file and store them in a structure.

The structure contains

```
char region
char country[100]
int country_code
```

The instance of this structure is called c[100]

The file i am trying to read in looks like this

```
Europe
0 France
1 England
2 Germany
```

There are an unkonwn number of countries, so it has keep reading until EOF.

I have created an array of the structures.

The code i have so far looks like this:

```
fp= fopen(countries,"r");

    while (!feof(fp))
    {
    fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]", c.region);
        while (!feof(fp))
        {
        fscanf(fp, "%d, %[^\n]", c[i].country_code, c[i].country);
        i++;
        }
    }
```

I get a segmentation fault. I'm sure its something obvious that ive missed out or done wrong, but im not sure what, and i would be grateful if anyone could help.

Comment: Don't use feof() to control loop. http://c-faq.com/stdio/feof.html

Answer (score 1):

```
fscanf(myfile, "%d, %[^\n]", c[i].country_code, c[i].country);
```

should be fixed to

```
fscanf(myfile, "%d, %[^\n]", &(c[i].country_code), c[i].country);
```

as fscanf needs an address to write data. You do not need to use `&` for char array, as it is already a pointer.

Also, in your structure `char region;` should be changed to `char region[100];` as you have not the one char for the region, but several ones, IOW a string.

Comment: -1 comma in formatspec is wrong here, fscanf-return are ignored

Answer (score 1):

```
 myfile = fopen(countries,"r");
```

Check the return value for errrs

```
while (!feof(myfile))
{
fscanf(myfile, "%[^\n]", c.region);
```

You need to pass the address of c.region: `&c.region`. However, it's still wrong as you're only allocating one character and fscanf will read characters until a non-match. You should change the declaration of c.region to be a character array `c.region[[00]` or something.

Also, c is an array, not a struct, so I don't think this is the code you're actually using. Did you mean c[0].region?

You should also worry about reading more than whatever you have allocated. Read up on fscanf's ways of limiting what it stores in the address passed

Where do you set i to zero?

```
    while (!feof(myfile))
    {
    fscanf(myfile, "%d, %[^\n]", c[i].country_code, c[i].country);
```

Again, you need to pass the address of the country_code field  `&c[i].country_code"` . Note that you do not need to use the & operator on the country field, even though the other answers so far say you do as country is a char array and so c[i].country is the same as &c[i].country

```
    i++;
```

What happens if there are more lines in the file than allocated  entries in the c[i] array?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the address of the country_code and country fields:

```
fscanf(myfile, "%d, %[^\n]", &c[i].country_code, &c[i].country);
```

Otherwize fscanf will intepret those two integer values as pointers, and try storing data into them => segmentation fault.

Comment: c[i].country is already a char array, no & here is necessary.

Comment: You're right that there is no need for & for country. However it is not a `char`, it is an array of char (`char[100]`). When passing an array of char as a parameter to a function, the compiler converts it into a char pointer `(char*)`.

Answer (score 0):

with struct like

```
char region[100]
char country[100]
int country_code
```

it should work eg.

```
char aregion[100]="", line[100];
...
while( fgets(line,100,myfile) )
{
  if( *aregion && 2==sscanf(line,"%d%99[^\n]",&c[i].country_code,c[i].country) )
    strcpy(c[i++].region,aregion);
  else
  if( !strchr(line,' ') )
    sscanf(line,"%99[^\n]",aregion);
}
```